# Is there a way to setup Brush Strength with the Wacom Touch Ring?

Tags: customization, shortcut, sculpting

I know that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will bring up a dynamic brush strength adjuster when I am sculpting, and I could assign that to one of my Wacom tablet's ExpressKeys, but there are only eight ExpressKeys and I would like to keep them for other functions.

I was wondering if there was a way to get the Brush Strength to increment up and down with hotkeys so that I could configure a custom Touch Ring Brush Strength command.